# Import a table on other file using php

Tags: php, html

So I have a php file with 10 tables... What I want is to export one of them to show on another php file, if I edit on this first file with the 10 tables, it will edit as well on the second file which kinda import the table from the first one. I tried include and require but doesn't do what I want, instead of export 1 table, exports the entire file... Is there any other way, that I don't know to do what I want?

Comment: Can you show your code here?

Comment: the code is quite long... is there any way to upload it?

Comment: Assuming that the table data are saved in database/xls/.txt file, then in each table, assign a unique identifier (id). In your export button, add this id and pass it to your next page (or your ajax request). Then re-create the table based on this unique id

Comment: what kind of files you want to upload?

Comment: a php one with 25k lines, too big to ctrl-v here

Comment: Just pick up a piece of that 25k code, that too broad, just be specific